# React-Hook-Form getValues and setValues not reflecting full current values

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

So I have a complex form, which is relying on dynamic data being brought in from different sources, compared, and a particular sub field array (goals) is set based on a toggle using setValue() with react-hook-form. I'm then using getValues() to pass the data to a child component which presents a signature field and adds that to the values prior to submit. However, in the dynamic fields, one of the values is not being passed by getValues, and my only guess is that it's inclusion is based on setValue even though if the object was changed before it should be there in the default values.

Some detail:

Parent form component:

```
const EditVisit = () => {

const hasVisit = useSelector(state => state.visit)
//Parent component is a child receiving an event prop from React FullCalendar, certain details are 
dispatched to redux-toolkit along with any prior edits to the visit object, and received here in this form.

const goals = hasVisit.goals

const values = getValues()
const goalValues = getValues(["goals"])
console.log("values: ", values, goalValues)
//I'll show the results of the log below

...

 const { register, handleSubmit, control, setValue, watch, getValues, formState: { errors, dirtyFields } } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
    visitStart: hasVisit.visitStart,
    visitEnd: hasVisit.visitEnd,
    location: hasVisit.location,
    goals: hasVisit.goals,
    status: hasVisit.status,
    cancelNote: hasVisit.cancelNote
    },
    shouldUnregister: true
  });
//RHF sets the values from the useSelector as defaults, all this works fine. The goals child array 
is the one I'm having issues with.

...

return (
...
{goals.length >= 1 ? ( goals.map((goal, index) => (
          <GoalInput 
            key={index}
            goal={goal} 
            index={index} 
            control={control}
            errors={errors}
            setValue={setValue}
          />
          
        
      ))
      ):(
        <Typography>No service plan with goals for this date. Goals must be set in the plan to reflect here.</Typography>
      )
    
    }
//The goals array of objects is set dynamically in another part of the app, and I use a custom hook 
that compares the base object with any prior edits and returns the needed set up, all this works fine. 
...

)
```

The goalInput component:

```
function GoalInput({ goal, index, setValue, control, errors }) {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (goal.marked === true) {
      setToggle(true);
    } else {
      setToggle(false)
    }
  }, []);

  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);





  return (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        type="checkbox"
        name={`goals.${index}.marked`}
        defaultValue={goal?.marked}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <Switch
            checked={toggle}
            onChange={(e) => {
              field.onChange(e)
              setToggle(!toggle);
              setValue(`goals.${index}.title`, goal.title)
//this is the field "title" that is not reflecting when the data is from a prior edit rather than being adjusted in the current instance
            }}
            value={field.value}
          />
        )}
      />
      <label>{goal?.title}</label>
      <br />
      {toggle ? (
        <>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name={`goals.${index}.note`}
            id={`goals.${index}.note`}
            defaultValue={goal?.note}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <TextField
                index={index}
                error={!!errors.note}
                value={field.value}
                onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e)}
                label="Progress Note"
              />
            )}
          />
          <br />
        </>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Below is the console.log of the getValues(). The first 2 are from prior edits, reflecting the status and note, but not the title field. The 3rd is from a current instance where the toggle was switched, triggering the setValue() call.

```
goals: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { marked: true, note: "Note says something" }
​​
1: Object { marked: true, note: "Saying something else" }
​​
2: Object { marked: true, title: "Cook", note: "something" }
```

So the behavior is clear to me, getValues() is pulling the prior edited values except the title field, and does accurately reflect the field when toggled in a current instance. However from a UX perspective, I can't tell people they have to toggle prior edits each time their ready to move on with the form for the signature component. I would expect that all prior default values would be included in the getValues(), like the marked field (which is the toggle itself) and the note, but the title which is set from the onChange event. This whole thing works fine on its own, and a different approach would be to just collect the signature, pass it back to this form in order to submit all values at the same time. However, I'm planning on reusing the signature component (which has the whole visit object and displays values for review) elsewhere in the app, so I was hoping to make this work from the current overall structure.

The [RHF getValues docs](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/getvalues) are a bit sparse, but I cant blame RHF, overall works amazing and this is a bit of a funky/ complex arrangement I'm doing.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to navigate around this, I'm all ears and appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I had a similar issue in the past. How I solved it is using `watch` instead of `getValues` to set other fields values. Also, with `watch` you can observe your state changes throughout the entire form so make sure the form field values actually change in the state not just in the user UI (whats displayed).

Comment: I like the thought, I use watch in other instances to monitor input changes and affect state, but as i've dialed this in, the issue isn't with getValues() itself, its that the setValue() call is tied to the onChange event for the toggle. Watch() returns the same values, and unless the toggle is switched it isn't collected. Although I'm still lost why that doesn't come through in the default values, the DB has the title field which should be getting to the form with the rest of the goal data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since the issue with the values not being collected by getValues() or useWatch() came from how the value for the goals.title was being set- in the onChange handler of the toggle, below is my work around. Through a useEffect to see if the goal had been marked before, if so, setValue() there.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(hasVisit) {
    hasVisit.goals.forEach((g, idx) => {
      console.log(g)
      if (g.marked) {
        setValue(`goals.${idx}.title`, g.title)
      }
    })
  }
}, [hasVisit])
```